# Plot integral in R

Tags: r

I'd like to plot a function which includes an intergral

```
# intergrand f
f <- function(r,x) x*exp(-r)

# integral
h <- function(x) {
    integrate(f, lower=0, upper=Inf, x=x)
}

plot(h, xlim=c(-2:4), xlab="x", ylab="y", col="red")
```

however, I get the following error message:

```
Error in integrate(f, lower = 0, upper = Inf, x = x) : 
  evaluation of function gave a result of wrong length
In addition: Warning message:
In x * exp(-r) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

I don't understand what this means. I hope you have a hint for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things going on here.

1. It looks like you want to integrate over `r`, not `x`. `integrate(...)` integrates `f` over values of the *first argument*, so you need to switch the order of the arguments to `f`.
2. `integrate(...)` returns a list with several elements. One of these is `value`, the value of the integral. So to get that you need to refer to `integrate(...)$value`. Read [the documentation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/integrate.html).
3. If you are going to use `plot(...)` with a function, the function needs to be vectorized. That is, it needs to take a vector as argument and return a vector of the same length. The `integrate(...)` function is one of the few in R that is not vectorized. Fortunately, there is a special function, `Vectorize(...)` that is designed to turn scalar-valued functions into vectorized functions.

Rolling this all up:

```
# intergrand f
f <- function(r,x) x*exp(-r)   # order of arguments reversed
# integral
h <- function(x) integrate(f, lower=0, upper=Inf, x=x)$value
g <- Vectorize(h)
x <- seq(-2,4,.1)
plot(x,g(x), xlim=c(-2,4), xlab="x", ylab="y", col="red")
```

[image]

As pointed out in the other answer, integrating `x*exp(-r)` over `r` on `[0,Inf]` yields `x`, so I really don't see the point of doing this. Nevertheless, this is how the code works.

Comment: `integrand <- function(x) {1/((x+1)*sqrt(x))}
h <- function(x) integrate(integrand, lower = 0.001, upper = Inf, x=x)$value
g <- Vectorize(h)
x <- seq(-2,4,.1)
plot(x,g(x), xlim=c(-2,4), xlab="x", ylab="y", col="red")` --> error: `Error in f(x, ...) : unused argument (x)`. Does your code only work for the function posted in the question?

Answer (score 2):

your h function returns a list with many variables and not a point that can be plotted.

It is not clear what you are doing, as h(x) simply returns x, as it is integrating over R, which integrates to 1.

Corrected code which would plot this is:

```
h<-function(x){
  x
}
plot(h, xlim=c(-2,4), xlab="x", ylab="y", col="red")
```

And note that the xlim has been changed, as well as the function.  If you wanted to integrate over x instead of R, note that the integral is

```
.5*exp(-r)*(x^2)
```

which might be a better way to do this.